# Select DOM element via VueJS

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension, vuejs2

I wrote a Chromium extension using clear JavaScript to interact with the DOM, but now I study VueJS and rewrote the extension to use Vue. I found one problem: there is one `<input>` element connected to Vue.

I change its value via the `bg.cp` property of the Vue instance, and now I need to select the DOM element. Is there any way to make text selection using the Vue instance instead of using `document.getElementById('test').select()`?

The final goal is to copy the `<input>` field to clipboard.

```
<body>
  <div id="appBg">
    <input v-model="cp" id="test">
  </div>
  <script>
  //vue instance of div with input field
  var bg = new Vue({
      el: "#appBg",
      data: {
        cp: ""
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: add a **reference** to it, and access it that way - https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-refs or https://codingexplained.com/coding/front-end/vue-js/accessing-dom-refs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use ref in DOM attribute and call it by $refs in js section

EX:

```
<input ref="inputName" />
```

and in js section call

```
this.$refs.inputName
```

here you can read [explanation](https://codingexplained.com/coding/front-end/vue-js/accessing-dom-refs) of it